# Query is not working in Postgres

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

Hi I want to construct a query

My table structure is

```
Nodeid         Nodename   Nodetype Parentid   nodedes
1              Node1         A      0         hghg
2              Node2         B      1         kjhjkh
3              Node3         A      0         gfhgfh
4              Node4         B      1         kjhjkh
```

If the nodettype is B , then the nodename of the node should get concatenated with the nodename of its parentid  like  NOde1-NOde4  or NOde1-node2

I am using hibernate and also how to convert this query into hibernate query
I am using postgres 
I have wwitten a query but it will work only one record is available..Its not wrking for multiple rows

```
SELECT nodename || '--' || (select nodename from table1 where nodetype='B')
FROM table1
WHERE nodeid in (SELECT table1.parentid FROM  table1  WHERE table1.nodetype = 'B')
```

CAn anyone please help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.nodename||'--'||b.nodename 
FROM table1 a, table1 b
WHERE b.nodetype='B' 
AND a.nodeid = b.parentid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a HQL query returning all the names of the nodes with type B, along with their parent node's name. The concatenation should not be done by the query. You should do this in your presentation logic.

```
select node.name, parentNode.name from Node node
inner join node.parent parentNode
where node.type = 'B'
```

This query returns a list of `Object[]`. Each `Object[]` contains the node nalme as its first element, and the parent node's name as its second element.